# calling function in background codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I want to send mail in the background, I have a function for it, and it's working fine, but it is blocking my message to pass to the user!

// i tried this

```
$er=1; 
$outmsg = 'You are now registered,please check your email for verification!';
$this->common_model->partialResponse();
$this->mailer->send_mail($mail,$Mailconfig);
$type = ($er==1) ? "success" : "danger";
echo json_encode(array('msgtype'=>$type,'datacon'=>$outmsg));



function partialResponse()
  {
     $response=array();
     ignore_user_abort(true);
     ob_start();
     echo json_encode($response);
     header("Status: 200");
     header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 200 Ok");
     header("Content-Type: application/json");
     header('Content-Length: '.ob_get_length());
     ob_end_flush();
     ob_flush();
     flush();
 }
```

Comment: why don't you do it last?

Comment: because i have 2 conditions one for some error and second for mailing and at last send error throw json ! ,but this message not passing to json

Comment: if I remember CodeIgniter has a Queue system for background processes

Comment: i dont know,but do you know how to use this function because i working great for my need, but the problem is its not passing $outmsg variable value to json_encode array..?

Answer (score 0):

Recently I endup with the same problem: slow email sending. Using SMTP is even worse. 3~4 seconds to send the e-mail.

At first thouths I think I could do something you are trying to archieve, but this method can cause so many problems, that did not worth it.

I endup creating a email table, to queue (and save as history) all emails that might be sent.

For process this queue I created a cronjob to run a specific controller/method just to send those emails.